# Swift Mutating Data at Range

Tags: swift, nsdata, unsafe-pointers

I am building a `Data` object that looks something like this:

```
struct StructuredData {
  var crc: UInt16
  var someData: UInt32
  var someMoreData: UInt64
  // etc.
}
```

I'm running a CRC algorithm that will start at byte 2 and process length 12.

When the CRC is returned, it must exist at the beginning of the `Data` object.  As I see it, my options are:

1. Generate a `Data` object that does not include the CRC, process it, and then build another `Data` object that does (so that the CRC value that I now have will be at the start of the `Data` object.
2. Generate the data object to include a zero'd out CRC to start with and then mutate the data at range `[0..<2]`.

Obviously, 2 would be preferable, as it uses less memory and less processing, but this type of an optimization I'm not sure is necessary anymore.  I'd still rather go with 2, except I do not know how to mutate the data at a given index range.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I do not recommend the way of mutating `Data` using this:

```
data.replaceSubrange(0..<2, with: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &self.crc, count: 1))
```

Please try this:

```
data.replaceSubrange(0..<2, with: &self.crc, count: 2)
```

---

It is hard to explain why, but I'll try...

In Swift, `inout` parameters work in copy-in-copy-out semantics. When you write something like this:

```
aMethod(&param)
```

- Swift allocates some region of enough size to hold the content of `param`,
- copies `param` into the region, (copy-in)
- calls the method with passing the address of the region,
- and when returned from the call, copies the content of the region back to `param` (copy-out).

In many cases, Swift optimizes (which may happen even in `-Onone` setting) the steps by just passing the actual address of `param`, but it is not clearly documented.

So, when an `inout` parameter is passed to the initializer of `UnsafeBufferPointer`, the address received by `UnsafeBufferPointer` may be pointing to a temporal region, which will be released immediately after the initializer is finished.

Thus, `replaceSubrange(_:with:)` may copy the bytes in the already released region into the `Data`.

I believe the first code would work in this case as `crc` is a property of a struct, but if there is a simple and safe alternative, you should better avoid the unsafe way.

---

ADDITION for the comment of Brandon Mantzey's own answer.

```
data.append(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &self.crcOfRecordData, count: 1))
```

Using *safe* in the meaning above. This is not *safe*, for the same reason described above.

I would write it as:

```
data.append(Data(bytes: &self.crcOfRecordData, count: MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size))
```

(Assuming the type of `crcOfRecordData` as `UInt16`.)

If you do not prefer creating an extra `Data` instance, you can write it as:

```
withUnsafeBytes(of: &self.crcOfRecordData) {urbp in
     data.append(urbp.baseAddress!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), count: MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size)
}
```

---

This is not referred in the comment, but in the meaning of above *safe*, the following line is not *safe*.

```
let uint32Data = Data(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &self.someData, count: 1))
```

All the same reason.

I would write it as:

```
let uint32Data = Data(bytes: &self.someData, count: MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size)
```

---

Though, observable unexpected behavior may happen in some very limited condition and with very little probability.

Such behavior would happen only when the following two conditions are met:

1. Swift compiler generates non-Optimized copy-in-copy-out code
2. Between the very narrow period, since the temporal region is released till the `append` method (or `Data.init`) finishes copying the whole content, the region is modified for another use.

The condition #1 becomes true only limited cases in the current implementation of Swift.

The condition #2 happens very rarely only in the multi-threaded environment. (Though, Apple's framework uses many hidden threads as you can find in the debugger of Xcode.)

In fact, I have not seen any questions regarding the *unsafe* cases above, my *safe* may be sort of *overkill*.

But alternative *safe* codes are not so complex, are they?
In my opinion, you should better be accustomed to use *all-cases-safe* code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I actually had a syntax error that was boggling me because I hadn't seen that before.

Here's the answer:

```
data.replaceSubrange(0..<2, with: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &self.crc, count: 1))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your code is not _safe_... Please check my answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't want to get too off topic, but it seems a bit much to start a new question.  By what you're saying in your answer, would you say that `data.append(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: &self.crcOfRecordData, count: 1))` is safe?

Comment: If not, what alternative would you recommend?  If you think I should just start a new question, please let me know.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just a moment, I will update my answer, as for now, I cannot have enough time.

Comment: Done. Please check the added part of my answer.